# What's the proper way to insert a row into ContentResolver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

This is my logic to insert a new row into ContentResolver (it is Xamarin, but don't think it is relevant except for some syntax may looks weird for non C# guys)

```
var contentResolver = ContentResolver;
var cv = new ContentValues();
String timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
cv.Put(MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Title, timeStamp);
var uri = contentResolver.Insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, cv);
```

I was expecting uri to reflect the `title` that I have set but instead it returns a uri like this one

> content://media/external/images/media/1546

The title I set is not present anywhere. What's the uri I'm getting from `Insert` and what's the proper way to make it honor the name I've set for the image?

**EDIT**

If I get `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data`, result is `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1483385168489.jpg`

If I get `MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Title`, result is `20170102_165627`

I expect to create a file with this name `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/20170102_165627.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the proper way to make it honor the name I've set for the
>   image?

`Query`  `ContentProvider` using `URI` for  `MediaColumns.TITLE`:

```
 // required column 
string[] proj = new[] { MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE };
 // query ContentProvider
ICursor cursor = contentResolver.Query(uri, proj, null, null, null);

// add null and empty check for cursor
 ....

// get column index
int column = cursor.GetColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE);
// read title from cursor using column index
string media_title = cursor.GetString(column);
```

Comment: This is 100% correct but the title doesn't seem to be the file name to be stored on content resolver on insert?. How do I set the end file name? If I get the `DATA` column I have `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1483385168489.jpg`

Comment: And my other question was: what's `content://media/external/images/media/1546`?

Comment: @StackOverflower: `1546` is auto generated  id for image in contentProvider db which you have inserted.

Comment: @StackOverflower: and you can also  get file name from `storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1483385168489.jpg` using `File` class

Comment: last question -> Notice that I'm trying to set file name to a date format like this one `yyyyMMdd_HHmmss`. Created file is not honoring that. That's the only missed piece on this puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: @StackOverflower: not possible have you checked what  value getting in `timeStamp` ? or using some static name like `20170103_012744` ?

Comment: Added a edit to my question to avoid adding more comments

Comment: @StackOverflower: Ok try after adding `cv.Put(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BucketDisplayName, timeStamp);`

Comment: Understood, that's not extremely important. It's a nice to have but the core issue is resolved. Thanks!